# How to insert an additional path into URL using PHP?

Tags: php, url, urlparse

Let say I've this URL:

http://example.com/image-title/987654/

I want to insert "download" to the part between "image-title" and "987654" so it would look like:

http://example.com/image-title/download/987654/

help would be greatly appreciated! thank you.

Comment: You can use string functions. one method is split the string '/' or reconstruct or replace the string '/image-title/987654' with your string.

Comment: assuming 987654 is a variable... just prepend it with **"download/"** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this in PHP:

- Split and reconstruct using explode(), array_merge, implode()
- Using substring()
- Using a regular expression
- Using str_replace

Assuming all the url's conform to the same structure (image-title/[image_id]) i recommend using str_replace like so:

```
$url = str_replace('image-title', 'image-title/download', $url);
```

If however image-title is dynamic (the actual title of the image) i recommend splitting and reconstructing like so:

```
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);
$urlParts = array_merge(array_slice($urlParts, 0, 3), (array)'download', array_slice($urlParts, 3));
$url = implode('/', $urlParts);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your URIs will always be the same (or at least predictable) format, you can use the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the URI into each of its parts, and then use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to insert elements into that array, and finally use [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to put it all back together into a single string.

Note that you can insert elements into an array by specifying the `$length` parameter as zero. For example:

```
$myArray = array("the", "quick", "fox");
array_splice($myArray, 2, 0, "brown");
// $myArray now equals array("the", "quick", "brown", "fox");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very well formatted, but i think this is what you need

```
$mystr= 'download';
$str = 'http://example.com/image-title/987654/';
$newstr = explode( "http://example.com/image-title",$str);
$constring =  $mystr.$newstr[1];


$adding = 'http://example.com/image-title/';
echo $adding.$constring;  // output-- http://example.com/image-title/download/987654/
```